# icefaces menu bar handling

Tags: icefaces

Can anyone please tell me method of handling action and action listener of a menu item?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [ICEfaces Component Showcase](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface)
has a Menu Bar example you can try directly in your web browser plus source code.  In the example,
an actionListener method in the Java Managed Bean is called when a menu item is selected.

There is also an ICEfaces tutorial for [Menu Bars](http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/menuBar-tutorial.html)
with examples you can download.